# Does Java allow type parameters for type parameters?

Tags: java, scala, generics, type-parameter, traits

In Scala you can do such things:

```
trait A[T]

trait B[C[_] <: A[_]] {
    def apply[T](entity: C[T]): T
}
```

The Java analog would look something like this:

```
interface A<T>

interface B<C<?> extends A> {
   <T> T apply(entity: C<T>): T
}
```

You can use B with any type that extends A and use this sub-type's type parameter as an output type of the method.

But it doesn't compile, how would you do it in Java?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)?

Comment: I'm trying to return from the function apply() the value of type T

Comment: I guess you should explore java.util package.

Comment: @feuerball can you rewrite it using generics?, I couldn't.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to explain in words what the Scala code does; currently, the question can only be answered by an expert in both languages.

Comment: I am not into Scala, but maybe you want something like [this](http://pastebin.com/pHBC06iK).

Comment: thanks, but C should be a type parameter and not actual type, it needs to be infered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you unfortunately can't do this. Java does not have higher kinded types.